# How to avoid race conditions on cursor.observe?

Tags: meteor

## Race condiditions

In my Meteor application, I made an `observe` within a `publish`, that insert some new data in certain conditions. The point is that sometimes we have *duplicated* subscriptions, and race condition leads us to duplicate inserted data.
If it is [not possible to have "singleton observers"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116711/599991):

- How can we avoid race conditions and duplicated inserted data on database?

**Example:**

```
Meteor.publish("fortuneUpdate", function () {
  var selector = {user: this.userId, seen:false};

  DailyFortunes.find(selector).observe({
    removed: function(doc, beforeIndex){
      if(DailyFortunes.find(selector).count()<1)
        createDailyFortune(this.userId);
    }
  });

}
```

*This question has been moved from [How cursor.observe works and how to avoid multiple instances running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095647/599991)*

Comment: Note that I didn't say it wasn't possible to do singleton observers, just that a certain class of them will be done automatically for you in a later release (I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116711/599991), it is not possible, for now, to  ensure that calls to subscribe that have the same arguments are shared.
So, if you are having the same problem I had, of redundant data created inside observers, I suggest you, as workaround, to:

1. Create *robust* [indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) that prevent repeted data creating. [Compound Keys](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys) is probable what you need here.
2. Treat duplicate key error exceptions inside your observer ignoring race conditions.

**example**:

```
Collection.find(selector).observe({
  removed: function(document){
      try {
        // Workaround to avoid race conditions > https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095647/599991
        createNewDocument();
      } catch (e) {
        // XXX string parsing sucks, maybe
        // https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3069 will get fixed one day
        if (e.name !== 'MongoError') throw e;
          var match = e.err.match(/^E11000 duplicate key error index: ([^ ]+)/);
        if (!match) throw e;
        //if match, just do nothing.
      }
    self.flush();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an odd pattern.  Can you share some example code?

Generally I'd either expect to see mutations in a method, or setting up an `observe` inside `Meteor.startup()` on the server.  (The latter is tricky if you're running multiple server processes, but so are many other things in a multi process regime.  We'll have a better pattern down the line.)

Because it can be arbitrary JS, a publish function has to run once per subscribing client.  It may log new subscriptions, set up per-client server state, or vary its behavior based on `this.userId` or even a random source.  For example, consider a subscription that returns 10 randomly selected documents from a DB collection to each subscribed client!

So the place to optimize the case of many clients subscribing to the same data set is at the DB query layer: if a thousand clients are subscribed to the same DB query, we'll just run that underlying query once.

Comment: I added one example, probably is easier to understand now.
I don't think that `Meteor.startup()` can handle database modifications based in what users are connected. Can it?