# Meteor/Mongodb observable collection getting called twice

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor/Mongo to create a chat app.

I have the following code, but my problem is when I add a row to the MongoDb, the `observe` gets triggered twice, when I only expect it to do so once.

The  `addMessage` function gets called twice. Is there a way to prevent `addMessage` from being called more than once for a particular `message`?

On the client:

```
private messages: Mongo.Cursor<Message>;

sendMessage(): void {
      this.messages.observe({
        added: (message) => this.addMessage(message)
      });    
      this.call('addMessage', this.senderId, this.activeChat._id, this.messageString);    
}
```

On the server:

```
  addMessage(senderId: string, chatId: string, content: string): void {
    Messages.insert({
      chatId: chatId,
      senderId: senderId,
      content: content,
      readByReceiver: false,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });
  },
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095647/how-cursor-observe-works-and-how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-running) is someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Need to make sure that the following is only done once. i.e singleton.

```
  this.messages.observe({
    added: (message) => this.addMessage(message)
  });
```

The issue was than many instances of the observer were being created, and each one was fireing

Answer (score -1):

The Observe gets calls twice because you are adding the record twice. Meteor looks after updating the db, you don't need to call a server method to do an insert

Comment: The issue is, that the Meteor Server only gets called once, but the observable is acting like it gets added twice.

Comment: I even do a `count` on the `cursor` and the value is the same on the first call of `addMessage` as the second.